# How do I exclude a field from the search filter in Rails Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

When I search for a user with 'test', it gives me a Postgres error because `category` is an integer.

> Started GET "/admin/user?model_name=user&utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=test" for ::1 at 2020-02-21 17:43:44 -0500
>   Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#index as HTML
>     Parameters: {"model_name"=>"user", "utf8"=>"√", "query"=>"test"}
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "test"
>   LINE 1: ...users.name ILIKE '%test%') OR (users.category IN ('test')) O...

I don't have `category` as a configured field for the model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include RailsAdminUser
```

---

```
module RailsAdminUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    rails_admin do
      list do
        fields :id, :email, :name, :company, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip
      end
```

I can't find how to exclude `category` from the fields that it wants to search. I'm OK with leaving that field out of the search. It seems to construct a query with every single field. I tried to hide the `category` field but that didn't work.

```
  list do
    configure :category do
      hide
    end
```

Fields docs: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields

Full docs: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki

rails_admin 1.4.2

---

I tried

```
  list do
    field :category do
      visible false
      filterable false
    end
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A previous developer had

`config\initializers\rails_admin_reload.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  RailsAdmin::ApplicationController.class_eval do
    before_action :reload_rails_admin, if: Rails.env.development? # Reloading RailsAdmin Config Automatically

    def reload_rails_admin
      RailsAdmin::Config.reset
    
      load("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb")
```

I added

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    xxx
  end
```

And

```
module RailsAdminUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    rails_admin do
      xxx
```

Which were not even throwing errors, so it was not even reading those files or methods. I assume they wanted to reload the Rails Admin configuration whenever it changed, but it seems to also discard any and all model configurations too! I commented out the `before_action` and it worked.

I also added

```
  list do
    field :category do
      visible false
      searchable false
    end
```

Rails Admin seems to cache the configuration for models so whenever you change the configuration (like `searchable true => false`) you have to restart the server. Very annoying.

Comment: I don't think it's something like a "cache". It's more like, the things you do under initiliazers are called only once when your project is initiliasing.